# Как найти произведение всех элементов двумерного массива?

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа

В произведении выводит всегда 0. С одномерным массивом все отлично, но при работе с двумерным, выводится 0.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = new int[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()) * 10;
        int r = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                r = r * a[i][j];
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, перенеси скобку за 10

```
a[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
```

А во-вторых, чему будет равно произведение, если в таблице окажется хотя бы один 0? Добавь ещё единицу:

```
a[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
a[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Метод [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) возвращает дробное число `double` в интервале *больше или равно `0.0` и меньше `1.0`*, которое при приведении к `int` становится равным `0`, т. е. у вас массив пустой! Целое *псевдослучайное* число в заданном интервале можно получить с помощью метода [`Random.nextInt(n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)):

```java
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt(10); // [0, 9]
```

Ваш код может выглядеть так:

```java
int[][] a = new int[3][3];
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        a[i][j] = 1 + random.nextInt(10); // [1, 10]
    }
}
int r = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        r = r * a[i][j];
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
// [[4, 2, 8], [8, 7, 8], [1, 9, 10]]
System.out.println(r);
// 2580480
```